# `this` pointer reference to normal vs virtual functions in superclass

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual-functions

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

struct Base {
  void callNormalFn() {
    normalFn();
  }
  void callVirtualFn() {
     virtualFn();
  }
  void normalFn() {
    printf("Base::normalFn\n");
  }
  virtual void virtualFn() {
    printf("Base::virtualFn\n");
  }
};

struct Derived : Base {
  void callNormalFn() {
    Base::callNormalFn();
  }
  void callVirtualFn() {
    Base::callVirtualFn();
  }
  void normalFn() {
    printf("Derived::normalFn\n");
  }
  virtual void virtualFn() {
    printf("Derived::virtualFn\n");
  }
};

int main() {
  Derived d = {};
  d.callVirtualFn();
  //=> Derived::virtualFn (why?)
  d.callNormalFn();
  //=> Base::normalFn (why?)
}
```

From [c++ virtual function call without pointer or reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276635/c-virtual-function-call-without-pointer-or-reference), my understanding says that:

- there is an implicit `this` pointer inside `Base::callVirtualFn()` or `Base::callNormalFn()`, e.g. `this->virtualFn()`
- the `this` pointer should point to the current object being operated on (in this case, the `Derived` class)

Why is then the `this` pointer resolves to different classes when calling normal vs virtual functions?

Comment: `virtual` functions are usually looked-up from a `vtable`, which is a table of member function pointers. So, even if you have a pointer or reference of base class type, it's `vtable` is that of the most derived class.

Comment: The details of virtual method management techniques are not part of the language standard; only the *behavior* is defined and mandated. Commonly, vendors use some implementation of a *virtual method table* (a.k.a a `vtable`), where the polymorphic overrides of derivations are managed. The base members are still available via namespace resolution if desired. (e..g `Base::virtualFn` can be invoked from either `Base` or `Derived` members directly, and, depending on permissions, even instances (`d.Base::virtualFn();`).

Comment: Here's an article describing how it could look like: [Demystifying Virtual Tables In C++ – Part 3 Virtual Tables](https://www.martinkysel.com/demystifying-virtual-tables-in-c-part-3-virtual-tables/). SO Q&A:s: [Virtual Table layout in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342126/virtual-table-layout-in-memory) and [C++ virtual table layout of MI(multiple inheritance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921372/c-virtual-table-layout-of-mimultiple-inheritance)

Comment: Did you expect the same behaviour? Why?

Comment: `this` always resolves to the type of the class the method is implemented on. What `virtual` does is change how the method is looked up. You should get a C++ textbook; it will explain in more detail.